# Lambda function in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, lambda

What s wrong with my code?
I dont understand why its not working.Something gone wrong with my lambda function.

```
var a=5;
var b=6;
function lambda_test(a){

    return function(a){
        return a*a;
    };
}
var c=lambda_test(a);
window.alert(c);
```

Answer (score 2):

The `a` in your inner function is shadowing the `a` in your outer function (which is, in turn, shadowing the outermost one — that's a lot of different `a`s for just a few lines of code!). Give the arguments *different* names.

You're also never *calling* the function you get back and store in `c`. Your call to `lambda_test` creates the function, but doesn't call it; you'd then do that by calling `c`:

```js
function lambda_test(outer){

    return function(inner){
        return outer * inner;
    };
}
var c=lambda_test(5);
alert(c(6)); // 30
```

Comment: no , as a result i have variable as a string.Changing names doesnt help.

Comment: @EdwardRyzhewski: No, there are no strings at all in your code until `alert` implicitly converts its argument to string for display. Read the above carefully, and try running it (that snippet is runnable).